# python pandas filter function regex behavior on MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like (see Appendix for code to generate the dataframe):

`fy                                                              2018          2019                                      tag                                                uom                                                                  Assets                                             USD  3.753190e+11  3.385160e+11                                      AssetsCurrent                                      USD  1.286450e+11  1.628190e+11                                      AssetsNoncurrent                                   USD  2.466740e+11  1.756970e+11                                      DeferredTaxAssetsDeferredCostSharing               USD  6.670000e+08           NaN                                      DeferredTaxAssetsDeferredIncome                    USD  1.521000e+09  1.141000e+09                                      DeferredTaxAssetsGoodwillAndIntangibleAssets       USD           NaN  1.143300e+10                                      DeferredTaxAssetsLiabilitiesNet                    USD  5.834000e+09  5.834000e+09                                      DeferredTaxAssetsNet                               USD  8.974000e+09  6.610000e+09                                      DeferredTaxAssetsOther                             USD  8.340000e+08  7.970000e+08                                      DeferredTaxAssetsPropertyPlantAndEquipment         USD  1.230000e+09  1.370000e+08                                      DeferredTaxAssetsTaxDeferredExpenseCompensation... USD  7.030000e+08  5.130000e+08                                      DeferredTaxAssetsTaxDeferredExpenseReservesAndA... USD  4.019000e+09  3.151000e+09                                      DeferredTaxAssetsUnrealizedLossesOnAvailablefor... USD  0.000000e+00  8.710000e+08                                      DerivativeAssetsReductionforMasterNettingArrang... USD  1.400000e+09  2.100000e+09                                      IncreaseDecreaseInOtherOperatingAssets             USD -1.055000e+09  5.318000e+09                                      NoncurrentAssets                                   USD  3.378300e+10  4.130400e+10                                      OtherAssetsCurrent                                 USD  1.208700e+10  1.208700e+10                                      OtherAssetsNoncurrent                              USD  2.228300e+10  2.228300e+10`

Which is a MultiIndex pivot table with indices `tag` and `uom`. My goal is to filter rows by the `tag` index using a regex and the [filter function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html). For example:

```
df.filter(regex="^Assets$", axis="index")
```

Which ideally would filter out the row:

`fy                                                              2018          2019                                      tag                                                uom                                                                  Assets                                             USD  3.753190e+11  3.385160e+11`

However, when I do so it outputs an empty dataframe:

`Empty DataFrame                                                                                                         Columns: [2018, 2019]                                                                                                   Index: []`

I'm able to circumvent this problem by using:

```
df.index.get_level_values("tag").str.contains("^Assets$")
```

or as a function

```py
search = lambda df, regex, index_name: df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(index_name).str.contains(regex)]
```

But this is way less satisfying to me. Am I missing something about the pandas filter function and how its regex input works? **It does not behave as expected, and my guess is it's because I have 2 indices: `tag` and `uom` thus the regex is failing in the `uom` index when I use `"^Assets$"` as my regex.** This is supported by using the regex `"^Assets$|USD"` which returns the entire dataframe because all rows have `uom=USD`, and it shows the filter function takes both indices into account. If this is the case, then how do I selectively choose index=`tag` for the filter function on a MultiIndex dataframe?

Appendix:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

levels = ['Assets',
         'AssetsCurrent',
         'AssetsNoncurrent',
         'DeferredTaxAssetsDeferredCostSharing',
         'DeferredTaxAssetsDeferredIncome',
         'DeferredTaxAssetsGoodwillAndIntangibleAssets',
         'DeferredTaxAssetsLiabilitiesNet',
         'DeferredTaxAssetsNet',
         'DeferredTaxAssetsOther',
         'DeferredTaxAssetsPropertyPlantAndEquipment',
'DeferredTaxAssetsTaxDeferredExpenseCompensationAndBenefitsShareBasedCompensationCost',
         'DeferredTaxAssetsTaxDeferredExpenseReservesAndAccruals',
         'DeferredTaxAssetsUnrealizedLossesOnAvailableforSaleSecuritiesGross',
         'DerivativeAssetsReductionforMasterNettingArrangements',
         'IncreaseDecreaseInOtherOperatingAssets',
         'NoncurrentAssets',
         'OtherAssetsCurrent',
         'OtherAssetsNoncurrent']
codes = ['USD' for i in range(len(levels))]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([levels, codes], names=['tag', 'uom'])
columns = pd.Int64Index([2018, 2019], dtype='int64', name='fy')
values = [[3.75319e+11,  3.38516e+11],
              [1.28645e+11, 1.62819e+11],
              [2.46674e+11,  1.75697e+11],
              [6.67000e+08,          np.NaN],
              [1.52100e+09,  1.14100e+09],
              [np.NaN,  1.14330e+10],
              [5.83400e+09,  5.83400e+09],
              [8.97400e+09,  6.61000e+09],
              [8.34000e+08,  7.97000e+08],
              [1.23000e+09,  1.37000e+08],
              [7.03000e+08,  5.13000e+08],
              [4.01900e+09,  3.15100e+09],
              [0.00000e+00,  8.71000e+08],
              [1.40000e+09,  2.10000e+09],
              [-1.05500e+09,  5.31800e+09],
              [3.37830e+10,  4.13040e+10],
              [1.20870e+10,  1.20870e+10],
              [2.22830e+10,  2.22830e+10]]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns, index=index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of the regex part of the filter function is short and easy to adapt for a multi-index scenario where you still want to only regex 1 part of the multi-index. I know this is not a direct answer to what you asked because you're right, as implemented the filter function does not handle multi-index.

I ended up here with the same problem and thought it might be a useful answer to others to post the code I have used, adapted from the pandas original:

```
import regex as re

def filter_multi(df, index_level_name, regex, axis=0):
    def f(x):
        return matcher.search(str(x)) is not None

    matcher = re.compile(regex)
    values = df.axes[axis].get_level_values(index_level_name).map(f)
    return df.loc(axis=axis)[values]
```

Using the code in your Appendix:

```
print(df)
print(filter_multi(df, index_level_name='tag', regex='^Assets$', axis=0))
print(filter_multi(df, index_level_name='fy', regex='^2019$', axis=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to first remove `uom` from your index, apply `filter` (which then will be applied to the only index `tag`) and add `uom` back to your index, as in

```
df.reset_index('uom').filter(regex="^Assets$", axis=0).set_index('uom', append=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter a unique value from the first part of a multi-index, you can just use `loc`:

```
df.loc[['Assets']]
```

which gives:

```
fy                  2018          2019
tag    uom                            
Assets USD  3.753190e+11  3.385160e+11
```

If for your real problem, filter must be used, you should reset the unused part of the index and set it back after filtering:

```
df.reset_index(level='uom').filter(regex='^Assets$', axis=0).set_index('uom', append=True)
```

Comment: This is true, however I'd like the regex functionality